# The cyclic subgroups of $GL_{3}(\mathbf{F}_{p})$

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-groups, finite-fields, abelian-groups

Let $p$ be an odd prime number and let $\mathbf{F}_{p}$ be the finite field of order $p$.
The group $H$ is a cyclic subgroup of $GL_{3}(\mathbf{F}_{p})$ such that there does not exist an abelian subgroup H' of $GL_{3}(\mathbf{F}_{p})$ with H $\subsetneq$ H'.

My question is that how to compute the number of such subgroups $H$ of $GL_{3}(\mathbf{F}_{p})$.

I think that we should first find some cyclic subgroups which satisfy this condition but I don't know how.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Have you looked at this question and and answer for $GL_2$: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/389652/96384 ? It might give you ideas.

Comment: If $Z$ is the center of $GL_3(\mathbf{F}_p)$ (=a cyclic group of order $p-1$ consisting of scalar matrices), and $H$ is any cyclic subgroup, then $H'=HZ$ is abelian. Therefore for $H$ to meet your condition we must have $Z\le H$.

Comment: A consequece of the preceding observation is that we must have $p\nmid |H|$. For every element of a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $GL_3$ is contained in an elementary abelian $p$-subgtoup of order $p^2$. The case of $GL_3$ differs from $GL_2$ for this reason. (I think that in $GL_2$ we could find a cyclic subgroup of order $p(p-1)$ with the prescribed property.

Comment: I think that any copy of the multiplicative group of the extension field $\mathbf{F}_{p^3}$ is an example of the kind of group you are looking for. It is cyclic of order $p^3-1$ and the theory around *double centralizers* suggests that any copy of a maximal field is its own centralizer in the matrix algebra. I also think that such groups are all conjugate (Skolem-Noether?). All the three field automorphisms are realized by conjugation (Skolem-Noether again), so the group has index three in its normalizer.

Comment: I dare not yet guess whether there are other groups with this property, but it would not surprise me, if there aren't.